# updating sqlite database to sort integers from highest value down

Tags: android, database, sqlite, integer

How would i go about this, i have COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_NAME and COLUMN_INTE

COLUMN_INTE holds long integers and I want it to be displayed on a List view, which it currently does just not descending from highest to lowest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write your query against your table with an ORDER BY clause that dictates a descending order with the DESC keyword.  Something like this should work:

```
string query = "SELECT COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_INTE FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY COLUMN_INTE DESC";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

String[] columns = new String[] { "COLUMN_ID", "COLUMN_NAME"};
int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

try {
      dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
           this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c, columns, to, 0
    );
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MY_LISTVIEW);
    lv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The statement will work on Android too..  Submit that using the SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery method

Answer (score 0):

You can also use comparator to do sorting . Like an example -

class MySalaryComp implements Comparator{

```
@Override
public int compare(Empl e1, Empl e2) {
    if(e1.getSalary() < e2.getSalary()){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: Use an SQL command that sorts for you or you can get the entire list and sort it yourself.

SQL command sorting:

```
    // Create an object to store rows from the table
    tableRowObject = new tableRowObject();
    String query = "select * from STATISTICS order by COLUMN_INTE";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if(cursor.getCount()<1) // COLUMN_INTE Not Found
    {
        cursor.close();
    }
    else
    {
        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            // Get COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_INTE
            int columnID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("COLUMN_ID"));
            String columnName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("COLUMN_NAME"));
            int columnInte = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("COLUMN_INTE"));

            // Add the variables to a new object
            tableRowObject.add(columnID, columnName, columnInte);
        }

        cursor.close();
    }
```

Sort yourself:

```
    // Create an object to store rows from the table
    tableRowObject = new tableRowObject();
    String query = "select * from STATISTICS";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if(cursor.getCount()<1) // COLUMN_INTE Not Found
    {
        cursor.close();
    }
    else
    {
        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            // Get COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_INTE
            int columnID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("COLUMN_ID"));
            String columnName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("COLUMN_NAME"));
            int columnInte = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("COLUMN_INTE"));

            // Add the variables to a new object
            tableRowObject.add(columnID, columnName, columnInte);
        }

        cursor.close();
    }
    // Sort the object
```